DAX equivalnt of GROUP BY and MIN - How do I count products launched, by year? - DAX / MS Fabric / Power BI
I want to create a measure that counts how many products were sold for the first time in a given year. That means if the product was sold in any year prior, it should not count in the current year.
I would expect to do something like this: (code can be run and iterated here: https://dax.do/fDTAmTl3kDIMaF/ )
DEFINE MEASURE 'Sales'[m1] = 
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT (Sales[ProductKey]),
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
                Sales[ProductKey],
                CALCULATETABLE ( Sales,
                        ALL( Sales[Order Date] ),
                        ALL( 'Date'[Date] ),
                        ALL( 'Date'[Calendar Year] )                        
                ),  
                "earliest_sale", MIN( Sales[Order Date] ) 
        ),
        ALL( Sales[Order Date] ),
        ALL( 'Date'[Date] )
    )

EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    'Date'[Calendar Year],
    "number of products sold for the first time", 'Sales'[m1]
)

However, this returns the following:



Calendar Year
number of products sold for the first time




CY 2009
1,513


CY 2007
1,258


CY 2008
1,478



Which is exactly the same result as the one I get from
EVALUATE 

SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    'Date'[Calendar Year],
    'Sales',
    "distinct product sales", DISTINCTCOUNT ( Sales[ProductKey] ),
    "total sales", COUNTROWS ( 'Sales' )
)

| Date[Calendar Year] | distinct product sales | total sales |
| ------------------- | ---------------------- | ----------- |
| CY 2009 | 1,513 | 39,793 |
| CY 2007 | 1,258 | 31,682 |
| CY 2008 | 1,478 | 28,756 |
Finally, going perhaps, a little bit crazy, I tried this:
EVALUATE 

SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    'Date'[Calendar Year],
    FILTER( 'Sales',
            Sales[Order Date] = CALCULATE(  MIN( Sales[Order Date] ),
                                            SUMMARIZE ( CALCULATETABLE ( 'Sales',
                                                                          ALL ( Sales[Delivery Date] ),
                                                                          ALL ( 'Date'[Date] ),
                                                                          ALL ( 'Date'[Calendar Year] )
                                                         ),
                                                         Sales[ProductKey]
                                            ),
                                            ALL ( Sales[Delivery Date] ),
                                            ALL ( 'Date'[Date] ),
                                            ALL ( 'Date'[Calendar Year] )
                                )
    ),
    "distinct product sales", DISTINCTCOUNT ( Sales[ProductKey] ),
    "sales", COUNTROWS ( 'Sales' )
)

And got:
| Date[Calendar Year] | distinct product sales | sales |
| ------------------- | ---------------------- | ----- |
| CY 2009 | 1,513 | 39,793 |
| CY 2007 | 1,258 | 31,682 |
| CY 2008 | 1,478 | 28,756 |
Any help would be much appreciated. I wan to count the number of products in each year that were never sold before then, i.e. were sold in that year, for the first time ever.

Try this measure pattern:
MyMeasure2 = 

VAR ProdSummary = 
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    Sales[Product ID]
    , "earliest"
    , MINX(Sales, [Order Date])
)

VAR thisYear = ALLSELECTED('_Date Table'[Date]) //Gets all dates for CY Year

VAR prodCount = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(ProdSummary)
            , FILTER(ProdSummary
                    , [earliest] in thisYear
            )
)

RETURN prodCount

Example Output:

I have a relationship from my _Date Table[Date]  to my Sales[Order Date].

Sample sales data used for this answer:



Order Date
Product ID




2022-02-04
P006


2023-01-21
P012


2021-01-11
P020


2023-05-21
P010


2021-11-14
P007


2022-12-08
P012


2023-04-27
P006


2020-05-17
P006


2023-08-03
P016


2021-08-24
P003


2023-02-23
P010


2022-02-07
P005


2023-05-11
P011


2022-11-18
P008


2020-03-10
P012


2022-09-01
P009


2021-03-25
P010


2021-08-18
P020


2024-06-04
P018


2022-02-28
P003



